# Split long arguments up in Python command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, multiline, args

How do you split up long arguments for a Python script using `argparse`?

Currently you would have to call a script with arguments, like this:

```sh
python myscript.py --argument1 "Value1" --argument2 "Value2" --argument3 "Value3" --argument4 "Value4" --argument5 "Value5" --argument6 "Value6"
```

However this can be write hard to read especially when you have a long list of arguments. Something like below would be much easier to read in my opinion. But when I try below I recieve the following error: `unrecognized arguments: \`

```sh
python myscript.py \
  --argument1 "Value1" \
  --argument2 "Value2" \
  --argument3 "Value3" \
  --argument4 "Value4" \
  --argument5 "Value5" \
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Or is this not possible at all?

In case anyone needs it; here is an example of my code:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--argument1')
parser.add_argument('--argument2')
parser.add_argument('--argument3')
parser.add_argument('--argument4')
parser.add_argument('--argument5')
parser.add_argument('--argument6')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: you can use path to text file containing all that arguments

Comment: why not to pass the argument list to the configuration file like json or csv and set only filename argument? I think it looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following keys for writing multi-line commands according to your system.

`\` works for Unix based systems.

`^` works for Windows command prompt.

`` ` `` works for Windows Powershell.

So, in your case, the command can be written as:

**For Windows command prompt**

```
python myscript.py ^
  --argument1 "Value1 is very very very ^
long long long string" ^
  --argument2 "Value2" ^
  --argument3 "Value3" ^
  --argument4 "Value4" ^
  --argument5 "Value5" ^
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

**For Windows Powershell**

```
python myscript.py `
  --argument1 "Value1 is very very very `
long long long string" `
  --argument2 "Value2" `
  --argument3 "Value3" `
  --argument4 "Value4" `
  --argument5 "Value5" `
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

**For Unix based systems**

```
python myscript.py \
  --argument1 "Value1" \
  --argument2 "Value2" \
  --argument3 "Value3" \
  --argument4 "Value4" \
  --argument5 "Value5" \
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

**TL;DR:** Use the `^` on windows cmd, `` ` `` on windows powershell & `\` on Unix/Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

For readability sake, assuming you are talking about `Value1`, `Value2`, ... being very long strings, you can do this.

```sh
python myscript.py \
  --argument1 "Value1 is very very very \
long long long string" \
  --argument2 "Value2" \
  --argument3 "Value3" \
  --argument4 "Value4" \
  --argument5 "Value5" \
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

Or you can assign the long argument string to a shell variable first.

```sh
ARG1="Value1 is very very very \
long long long string"
python myscript.py \
  --argument1 "${ARG1}" \
  --argument2 "Value2" \
  --argument3 "Value3" \
  --argument4 "Value4" \
  --argument5 "Value5" \
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this.

- Use a config file. As others have said this is the standard because it's clean, familiar and easy to use. Python has [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for dealing with this.
- Have commands which lead to recalling and asking from a list of other options. This would be something like:

```py
python myscript.py
...
>>> Which of the following would you like to do?
>>>0. Do x
>>>1. Do y
>>>2. Do z
...
1
>>> Doing y, which subcommand would you like to use:
>>>0. Do a
>>>1. Do b
...
```

You can do this with argparse or more simply with just `input()`

- Have argparse flags which have subcommands. Basically, this involves hiding some commands behind other commands. So instead of having options 1->6, you might have options 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b. So you might enter something like:

```py
python myscript.py --option_2 --option_a
```

- Alternatively, you could run the script from a file. Put all of the commands into a file, then have a small script (example below) run your main script. Each argument can be supplied on a separate line in the file. For example:

```py
import subprocess as sp

def execute_script():
    with open('arguments.txt') as args_file:
        args = args_file.readlines()
    sp.run(f'python myscript.py {*args}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't to do with python, it depends on your terminal. In bash (linux) your command works, because `\` tells the shell you are continuing the command on the next line. I'm going to assume you're using `cmd` in Windows. In this case the equivalent operator is `^`, so simply write:

```
python myscript.py ^
  --argument1 "Value1" ^
  --argument2 "Value2" ^
  --argument3 "Value3" ^
  --argument4 "Value4" ^
  --argument5 "Value5" ^
  --argument6 "Value6"
```

the same applies for scripts (`.sh`, `.cmd` files etc). In powershell, the operator is backtick, fyi.